# Unable to upload a file to a remote ftps server

Tags: ssl, curl, ftp

I have a scenario where I need to upload a file to a remote FTP server. The machine from which I am trying to upload this file is inside a AWS-VPC and behind a SOCKS server, now I am using the following command to do so

```
 curl --connect-timeout 90 -T nishant.txt  ftps://ftp.box.com/RANDOM_FOLDER/nishants.txt --user "username:password" -x socks://internal-proxy-elb-7288384.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:1080 -v
```

Now when I run this, it established the connections and sends the file also to the remote FTP server, but the file which is uploaded to remote server is *empty*.

The error I receive by running the above file is:

```
> STOR nishants.txt
< 150 File status okay; about to open data connection.
* Doing the SSL/TLS handshake on the data stream
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSL re-using session ID
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
{ [data not shown]
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ftp.box.com:990
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:04 --:--:--     0
* Closing connection 0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
} [data not shown]
curl: (35) Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to ftp.box.com:990
```

I am running the following curl version:

```
curl 7.35.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.35.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 librtmp/2.3
```

OpenSSL version:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the server you are trying to connect to does not like the protocol or cipher.

1. Try using sslv2

   ```
   curl --sslv2 --connect-timeout 90 -T nishant.txt  ftps://ftp.box.com/RANDOM_FOLDER/nishants.txt --user "username:password" -x socks://internal-proxy-elb-7288384.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:1080 -v
   ```
2. You could be trying to connect to the site using an ssl cipher that the site is configured to reject.Try using curl with `--ciphers ALL` option. Also, try testing an openssl connection

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect ftp.box.com:990
   ```

   ```
   openssl s_client -connect ftp.box.com:990 -ssl3
   ```
3. The results of the above commands may also indicate whether this is a bug with curl or not. You could try to downgrade curl to 7.33.0-3.

**Edit 1**

I tested the remote site using openssl commands. It seems SSL2/3 is not supported. You need to use TLSv1 with ciphers DES-CBC3-SHA.

Try this

```
curl -1 --connect-timeout 90 -T nishant.txt  ftps://ftp.box.com/RANDOM_FOLDER/nishants.txt --user "username:password" -x socks://internal-proxy-elb-7288384.eu-central-1.elb.amazonaws.com:1080 -v
```

If you receive the same error, try specifying the ciphers mentioned above using `--ciphers` option.

Comment: When i try option 1 , it says * OpenSSL was built without SSLv2 support * and quites, when i try option 2 , it simply quits

Comment: Edited the answer. It seems the server uses TLSv1

Comment: So  i get the same error, i have a feeling with https://curl.haxx.se/docs/knownbugs.html#FTPS_over_SOCKS